# Virtual box graphic issues when launched in another x session?

Tags: 12.10, xorg, virtualbox, virtualization

When I start virtual box in another x session under tty8, I get some strange results. Everything appears to be normal but when I boot up my Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit system aero does not work. However if I load this same virtual machine in the regular session that is started when logging in nothing is wrong and aero works fine.  The command I use is "xinit virtualbox -- :1"    Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect it has to do with hardware acceleration passed through to the VM.

Comment: It may also be (just my humble guess here) that your graphics driver has issues with multiple X sessions.

Comment: I use the regular open souce radeon drivers that come with the install. I never try to set up the closed source flgrx ones, they never worked. My graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 4200 built in my laptop.